# "No datasets found" after stopping/starting ckan docker containers

Tags: ckan

Added datasets don't show up anymore after doing `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up -d`

I installed a docker ckan instance according to the instructions on https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/installing/install-from-docker-compose.html and did some minor configuration tweaks and other setup stuff like nginx and ssl.

CKAN operated just fine. I can add organizations, groups and datasets and upload resources. Strangely after restarting the docker with the commands mentioned above the datasets don't show up anymore when I browse the orgs and groups.
The data is still there though. It is listed in the activity streams and I can access the datasets from there.

Is there a bug or did I break some things during installation/configuration? I'm new to CKAN and don't really know how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using docker-compose down the solr service persistent volume is removed. You will need to [rebuild the search index](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/paster.html#rebuild-search-index). Please, check this discussion for more info: [Bad dataset persistence after docker-compose down](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/4425)